# When calling set_index with more than one column, datetime.date values are converted to pd.tslib.Timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

As per title, pandas is force converting datetime.date types into pd.tslib.Timestamp types when I do a set_index, but ONLY if there is more than one column in the index. This makes working with and merging different frames a problem since some end up with Timestamps and others stay as datetime.dates. Super simple example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[datetime.date(2021,3,3),datetime.date(2021,3,4)],'player':['a','b'],'score':[10,9]})

print(type(df['date'][0]))
<class 'datetime.date'>

df = df.set_index('date')

print(type(df.index.get_level_values('date')[0]))
<class 'datetime.date'>

df = df.reset_index()

print(type(df['date'][0]))
<class 'datetime.date'>

df = df.set_index(['date','player'])

print(type(df.index.get_level_values('date')[0]))
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>

df = df.reset_index()

print(type(df['date'][0]))
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

How can I keep them in datetime.date?

[note: pd.**version** == '0.19.2' due legacy code, if it is relevant]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is bug, in my opinion.

You can use [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html) with set to `dates` by [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['date','player'])

df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[0].date, level=0)

print(type(df.index.get_level_values('date')[0]))
<class 'datetime.date'>

df = df.reset_index()

print(type(df['date'][0]))
<class 'datetime.date'>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - do you know if the bug is present in later pandas versions?
Also, your one-liner beats my 7-liner workaround, thanks.

Comment: @tim654321 - tested in pandas `1.2.3` and same problem like yours.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, but I do hope a better answer can be offered, since this is a pretty inefficient way and takes quite a few lines.

Workaround:

1. set the multiindex as normal
2. Unstack until only your date col remains as the index
3. Convert the values back to datetime.dates and set the index via a list, and give the index its name again
4. Stack the df back to its original layout

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[datetime.date(2021,3,3),datetime.date(2021,3,4)],'player':['a','b'],'score':[10,9]})
df = df.set_index(['date','player'])
df = df.unstack()
df.index = [d.date() for d in df.index.to_pydatetime()]
df.index.names = ['date']
df = df.stack()
print(type(df.index.get_level_values('date')[0]))
<class 'datetime.date'>
```